# What does the equation $h^k = \sigma(x * W^K + b^k)$ mean in the context of convolutional neural networks (CNNs)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, convolution

I was reading [a paper on CNN for auto-encoders](http://people.idsia.ch/~masci/papers/2011_icann.pdf) and in section 3 they had the following section:

> For a mono-channel input $x$ the latent representation of the k-th
>   feature map is given by $$ h^k = \sigma(x * W^k + b^k )$$ where the
>   bias is broadcasted to the whole map, $\sigma$ is an activation
>   function (we used the scaled hyperbolic tangent in all our
>   experiments), and $*$ denotes the 2D convolution. A single bias per
>   laten map is used, as we want each filter to specialize on features of
>   the whole input (one bias per pixel would introduce too many degrees
>   of freedom).

but I wasn't sure if I understood that equation properly. One of the things that is confusing me in particular is the index $k$. When they write $h^k$, is $h^k \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. is $h^k$ a single number or a vector (or a matrix)? The reason I am not sure is because the equation they have there is doing the convolution and the convolution outputs vectors (or in fact, functions). Therefore, it didn't quite make sense to me what was going on, specially because they mention that $*$ was the 2D convolution. Also, is what is $W^k$ indexing? A row of $W$ and column of $W$? Is $b^k$ a vector or a single number? Also, I don't think I even know if $x$ is a vector or a matrix, or an image, that wasn't clear either. Does someone know what is going on?

So as a list/summary:

1. What are the dimensions of the mathematical objects in question? $x$, $W$, $W^k$, $x * W^k$, $b^k$, $b$, $h$, $h^k$ (hope I didn't miss any).
2. What does the convolution return in this context? The usual convolution conv2 that matlab implements? $(x * k)[i,j] = \sum_n \sum_m x[m,n]k[i -m, j -n]$?
3. What is going on with the indexing $k$?

Comment: Perhaps http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Feature_extraction_using_convolution will help you understand it.

Comment: Note that the convolution used for CNN's are quite different from 'normal' convolution.

Answer (score 2):

I will be answering in terms of a usual CNN that is applied to an image.

1. $x$ is the input i.e. the pixels. A convolutional layer in a CNN works by passing over a filter over the data. Here each filter is denoted by $k$. Therefore $W^k$ is the learnable weights for a single filter and $W$ is the weights for all filters. Each filter also has a bias, $b^k$.
2. The convolution operation for a single filter returns a new 2D matrix $x * W^k$. This is simply an elementwise multiplication of the filter weights with the input. As the filter dimensions is usually smaller than the input dimensions, the filter is passed over different subsections of the data, thus yielding a new 2D matrix (see [deeplearning.stanford.edu](http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Feature_extraction_using_convolution)  for an example). When applying multiple filters (as is always the case), a new 3D matrix is created as the filter outputs are stacked on top of each other.
3. $k$ denotes the different convolutional filters.

Comment: so $h^k$ is of the same dimensions as the 2D matrix $x * W^k$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: so that means that we have $k$ number of convolved (hidden) features? One for each different filter?

Comment: The terminology is rather weak concerning what a "feature" is. I would rather say that we have $k$ number of feature detectors as each filter will detect a different kind of pattern. The same filter can generate multiple features, which is just the degree to which that pattern is present in different parts of the input.